# wxwidgets saveFile

Tags: wxwidgets

Im trying to draw a simple picture and save it to a file in wxwidgets. This is the code i have so far. However this code will never create the test.png picture.

```
    wxBitmap myBitmap;
    wxMemoryDC dc;
    dc.SelectObject(myBitmap);
    wxFont font=dc.GetFont();
    font.SetPointSize(15);
    dc.SetTextForeground(*wxBLACK);
    dc.DrawRectangle(0,0,50,100);
    wxString s(_T("A"));
    dc.DrawText(s, 5,5);
    wxString test(_T("images/test.png"));
    myBitmap.SaveFile(test, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

Can somebody please help me out in what I'm doing wrong...
/Mike

Answer (score 4):

First a piece of general advice: Use the debug version of wxWidgets, it will often assert whenever you did something wrong.

First you call the default `wxBitmap` constructor, resulting in an object that can not be used as-is. If you change your first line to

```
wxBitmap myBitmap(200, 200);
```

you will instead create a bitmap of 200 pixels width and height, which can actually be selected into the dc and be painted on. Alternatively you can call [`wxBitmap::Create()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxbitmap.html#wxbitmapcreate) before you use the bitmap.

Also, in order to save as a PNG file you need to register the PNG image handler (see the [`wxImage` documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wximage.html)) first. It's probably easiest to register all default image handlers by calling [`::wxInitAllImageHandlers()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_appinifunctions.html#wxinitallimagehandlers).

Finally you need to make sure that there is a subdirectory *images* under your current directory. Or use a file name with an absolute path. You would however get a message box at runtime if the saving of the bitmap failed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to unselect the bitmap from the DC before saving it too:

```
dc.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
myBitmap.SaveFile(test, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I would check the return of the call to SaveFile, if it returns true then it should be succeeding, otherwise there is a failure somewhere else.

Secondly try giving a full path rather than just images/test.png as depending on the current working directory of you program it might not put the file where you think it should.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

"test" = image output name.

".png" image output extention

"wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG" = wxBitmap image type. see: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/gdicmn_8h.html#a90a1eb6d85b5044a99b706fd979f27f5 for more explanation of types !

"SaveFile" = wxBitmap save file.

"wxBitmap myBitmap;" = variable in your example.

"wxString myPath(wxGetCwd());" = varibale wxString equivalent : "wxstring myPath; myPath = wxGetCwd(); Returns the path of the app folder in myPath variable. wxString myPath is variable type wxString wxGetCwd() return path app folder. wxString myPath(wxGetCwd()); is path for app folder sets in myPath variable!

example complete:

```
wxString myPath(wxGetCwd());
wxBitmap myBitmap;
myBitmap.SaveFile(localAtual + wxT("//test.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

Comment: If you were to add a bit of explanation it would make your reply more valuable.